# How to Convert Value into 2 decimal in expression column of data table

Tags: c#, datatable, expression

I want to convert value into 2 decimal part in expression column of DataTable.

e.g.
value = 23.2546876

i want = 23.25

please help me....

Comment: dtTable.Columns["Ratio"].Expression = "IIF(Width = 0, 0, Length/Width)";  width.length,ratio is decimal(6,3) column and i want result in decimal(6,2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution ....

there is no function for the convert value into 2 decimal 
but you might try using the following expression: 
Convert(x * 100, 'System.Int32')/100

Comment: In this case 123.40 will result in 123.4 - it does not guarantee 2 d.p.

Answer (score 5):

We'd need to know more details about the context, but I strongly suspect you shouldn't try to change the data within the `DataTable`. Instead, change how it's *displayed*. That's typically the most appropriate time to perform rounding operations.

Likewise, you should also check that you're using the most appropriate type - you haven't said whether you've currently got a `decimal` or a `double`, but the most appropriate type to use depends on what that value is trying to represent.

Comment: dtTable.Columns["Ratio"].Expression = "IIF(Width = 0, 0, Length/Width)"; width.length,ratio is decimal(6,3) column and i want result in decimal(6,2)

Comment: @Patel: Why though? Why do you want the value in a particular form *within the table*? Do you have to even perform the calculation in the `DataTable` itself at all? Personally I try to stay away from `DataTable` and instead use a collection of POCOs - it makes the data much easier to work with, IME.

Comment: if user enter length/width in datagridview then auto calculate ratio

Comment: @Patel: So you only need the *display* to be rounded to two decimal places? Put that in the format string for the column.

Comment: not only display but based on ratio value i make another calculation based on ratio and i am also save ratio value in database

Comment: @Patel: So do you really want to lose the extra information before saving the data? That sounds like a bad idea to me. You normally *calculate* with as precise information you can.